# Average Yearly Return: is this correct?

Tags: compound-interest

If an initial investment of 100'000 results in 200'000 after 10 years (including the initial investment), is it correct to say that the investment has returned on average 10% per year?

I am guessing the answer is 'no' due to compounding returns having a non-linear effect, but I can't quite more formally explain it to myself. Or perhaps it is correct and I'm just overcomplicating things?

Can anybody shed some more rigorous light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your guess is correct. You are not overcomplicating things. Compound interest is a real effect.**

The correct formula for compound interest is (200000/100000)^(1/10) = 1.0718

So, it has yielded only 7.18% per year. This is assuming the 200000 includes all returns, such as dividends. If not, you need to do a more complicated calculation.